# "undef. ref. to XX" and readelf shows "XX UND"

Tags: linux, usb, mips, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile usb_modeswitch for mips. The compilation worked successfully but it fails at runtime!

```
# ./usb_modeswitch -W -c zoom_modem_switch 
...
./usb_modeswitch: symbol lookup error: /umx/lib/libusb-0.1.so.4: undefined symbol: libusb_init
```

However, readelf seems to see the function but with the "UND" as Ndx value, what does it mean? Undefined? So why is it listed here if not defined ?

```
$ ${CROSS_COMPILE}readelf -s libusb-0.1.so.4  | grep libusb_init
    54: 000037b0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND libusb_init
   115: 000037b0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND libusb_init
```

Very frustrating! What am I missing ?